# Retrieve all the facebook public profile information using Spring Social

Tags: facebook, spring-social

I'm trying to retrieve the public profile information from facebook using Spring Social.
I was able to retrieve everything except for age_range.

Please suggest me some possibilities where I could retrieve the age range info.

Note: I don't want to retrieve any extended profile info. I just want the public profile.

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far?

Comment: I used auth code to connect to facebook. then used facebook spring social to login to facebook. Once it redirects to the redirect URL.I used FacebookProfile fbProfile=fbConn.getApi().getUserOperations().getGender() to get the gender of that particular facebook profile. But, I was not able to get the age range(which is one of the permissions in public profile) for that corresponding profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rest Operations solved the problem.

FacebookProfile profile = fb.restOperations().getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=age_range", FacebookProfile.class);
Age_range can be obtained by using profile.getExtraData which is in Map format.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Could you provide some details bout *how* the information in this link solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The age_range is not really a valueable info, it only contains the differentiations 13-17, 18-20 or 21+. I guess Spring Social is not supporting this field currently.

The page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ is stating

> Use any available public profile information before asking for a
>   permission. For example, there is an age_range field included in the
>   public profile for anyone who installs your app. This field may be
>   sufficient for your app instead of requesting user_birthday
>   permission.

As far as I understood you're using an app already?

Comment: Yes, we already have an app. we need only the differentiations i.e. age_range. We would like to retrieve it server side.